# Did Google Sheets publish URLs start using redirects?

Tags: google-sheets, redirect, https, export-to-csv

I have a Google Sheets document and using the CSV publish URL with a custom control system application that loads and parses data. It was a URL in the format of "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/longurlstring/pub?output=csv". This stopped working recently and I am wondering if there was an internal Google Sheets change that broke things.

When I test things in Insomnia REST API testing software, I get a 307 Temporary Redirect HTTP code. I am wondering now if this was a recent change to use a redirect and the URL previously loaded without redirect.

Our code hasn't changed in years but the loading of our URL stopped working within the past month or so, so the changes are definitely on Google's side.

I'm looking for some insight or confirmation on the matter, and perhaps a resolution. I don't think I can tell my application to just "follow redirects".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62550739/1595451